# How to capture user's phone number and location using Telegram Bot API?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I'm currently playing with telegram bot api via the telegram python package. So far I don't have any problem creating custom keyboards with the following code:

> bot.sendMessage(chat_id,
>                          text="Where are you now? "
>                               "/cancel to abort",
>                          reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['Home', 'Office']], one_time_keyboard=True))

Basically the above will give me two button, "Home" and "Office".

I'm now trying to capture user's phone number and location, which should be doable based on the Telegram API Bot documentation at https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton. However I'm really having a hard time figuring out how to get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

here is an example:

```
reply_markup = telegram.ReplyKeyboardMarkup([[telegram.KeyboardButton('Share contact', request_contact=True)]])

bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, 'Example', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Hope it  helps!

Answer (score 6):

from telegram import (KeyboardButton)

...
...
...

```
location_keyboard = KeyboardButton(text="send_location",  request_location=True)           #creating location button object
contact_keyboard = KeyboardButton('Share contact', request_contact=True)  #creating contact button object
custom_keyboard = [[ location_keyboard, contact_keyboard ]] #creating keyboard object
reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard) 
update.message.reply_text(
                "Would you mind sharing your location and contact with me?", 
                reply_markup=reply_markup)
```